# What is the point of Org-agenda?

Tags: org-agenda, calendar, diary

I'm very new to GNU Emacs. The first thing I need is to schedule deadlines for events. As far as I understand, Org is at the core an outliner, so why come up with an Org agenda rather than implement, through Org, outline facilities which operate on top of the standard emacs calendar/diary?

I'm very confused!

Comment: Did you take a look at the manual for [org agenda](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html)? Especially [this part](https://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html) seems to deal with integrating agenda into the emacs calendar and diary system.

Comment: Did you take a look at my question? Especially the third sentence seems to ask about the purpose behind Org agenda given that Emacs diary/calendar already exists.

As for the manual extract you link to, it makes me even more confused because it seems to suggest that Emacs diary/calendar don't provide the facility to schedule one-time events (which is where Org agenda comes into play), but this is wrong.

Comment: I guess if your only objective is to keep track of deadlines, the Emacs calendar is enough. Org agenda is about collecting and filtering dates which may be scatttered among various org files.

Comment: This is very useful information! Are you saying that the Emacs diary/calendar usually only fetches one file, whereas the Org agenda usually gathers data from a tree of .org files?

Comment: Yes, he is saying that. The best thing to do is read the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html) and find [examples](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html) of "real" usage. But you have to be patient: the agenda is very powerful, but there a lot of capabilities and a lot of details, so it is going to take time and effort. Start simple and build on that.